# Manual kth Nearest Neighbor Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, knn, euclidean-distance

I have to modify the following code in order to use 1, 3, and 5 neighbors and print the accuracy of each one. I can not use the sklearn library KNeighborsClassifier so I am stuck because I don't know how to modify k neighbors value here.

Code:

```
shuffle_df = dataset.sample(frac=1)

train_size = int(0.75 * len(dataset))

train_set=shuffle_df[:train_size]
test_set=shuffle_df[train_size:]

testarray=[]

for w in range(37):
   sepallengthtest = test_set.iloc[w,0]
   sepalwidthtest = test_set.iloc[w,1]
   petallenghttest = test_set.iloc[w,2]
   petalwidthtest = test_set.iloc[w,3]
   classtest = test_set.iloc[w,4]

   trainarry=[]
   for m in range(111):
       sepallengthtrain = train_set.iloc[m,0]
       widthtesthtrain = train_set.iloc[m,1]
       petallenghttrain = train_set.iloc[m,2]
       petalwidthtrain = train_set.iloc[m,3]
       classtrain = test_set.iloc[w,4]
    
       distance = sqrt((sepallengthtest-sepallengthtrain)**2 + (sepalwidthtest-widthtesthtrain)**2 + (petallenghttest-petallenghttrain)**2 + (petalwidthtest-petalwidthtrain)**2)
    
       if len(trainarry)==0:
           trainarry.append([distance, classtest, classtrain])
       if trainarry[0][0]>distance:
           trainarry.pop(0)
           trainarry.append([distance, classtest, classtrain])
  testarray.append(trainarry)

count=0
for i in range(37):
    results = testarray[i]

if results[0][1] == results[0][2]:
    count+=1
print(count)
accuracy=count/len(testarray)
print(f"\n Accuracy{accuracy: .3%}")
```

Output:

```
   Neighbors:       1       3       5             
   Success Rate:  86.8%    89.5%    89.5%
```